# Format chart colours based on series values

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to format the colours of a bar chart with a single series based on their values, i.e. anything over 50 would be green, anything below would be red?

What I currently have to do is a workaround:

I have my data for the original series, and then I create 2 subsets. One for red, one for green,
and use an if statement to pull through only values above 50 for the green series, and below 50 for red series, then plot both the series, obviously where one has gaps, the other doesn't.

But this is annoying, I would much prefer for an easy way to set a conditional format on the actual series itself.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Enter following VBA code as Module:*

```
Sub FormatChartbyColour()

Set rRng = Selection


ColorIndex1 = 3
ColorIndex2 = 4



ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rRng
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)


ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "=""Colour 1"""
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Colour 2"""


ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ThisWorkbook.Colors(ColorIndex1)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ThisWorkbook.Colors(ColorIndex2)

With ActiveChart.Parent
    .Height = 250
    .Width = 250
    .Top = 100
    .Left = 100
End With

ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = 10
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Bold = False
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Italic = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Chaert Title (Colour1:Red , Colour2:Green)"
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 10


With ActiveChart
    vX = .SeriesCollection(1).XValues
    vY = .SeriesCollection(1).Values


    For thisvY = 1 To UBound(vY)
        If vY(thisvY) = 1 Then .SeriesCollection(2).Points(thisvY).Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex1
        If vY(thisvY) = 2 Then .SeriesCollection(2).Points(thisvY).Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex2

    Next thisvY

End With


End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Select Data Range `A23:C27`.
- RUN the Macro.

**Note:**

- **Col Index** is *Helper Column*, you may alter `Colors`.
- Chart Type & Size are editable.
- Adjust cell references as you need.

Comment: Hey @Rajesh S, thanks for the answer, but having 2 series, one for each colour is what I already do as a work around. I was looking for a way to set two colours conditionally one a single series

Comment: @PeterH,, I think in that case you need Clustered Bar graph,, or if possible share Some sample data so I can try also. ☺